# Fast method to find what range contains a number

Tags: java, performance, range

#### The question:

Given an arbitrary double lower bound, double upper bound, and double increment, what is the **fastest** way to determine what range a given input double? Can you do better than the obvious way that uses double division if you don't care about memory usage, using precalculation or some such? Note: repeated uses of this class are not likely exactly the same double values, in other words, caching the result in a `Map<Double, Double>` probably will not help.

#### Straightfoward answer:

```
public class RangeFinder {
    private double lowerBound;
    private double higherBound;
    private double increment;

    public RangeFinder(double lowerBound, double higherBound, double increment) {
        if(increment < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Increment cannot be negative!");
        this.lowerBound = lowerBound;
        this.higherBound = higherBound;
        this.increment = increment;
    }

    public int getRange(double number) {
        if (number < lowerBound) return 0;
        if (number > higherBound) number = higherBound;
        return (int) Math.round((number - lowerBound) / increment);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        double lower = 2.3d;
        double higher = 3.9;
        double inc = 0.1d;

        double[] inputs = { 0.5d, 2.25, 2.35, 2.4, 3.0, 3.8, 3.85, 3.9, 4.0 };

        RangeFinder rf = new RangeFinder(lower, higher, inc);

        System.out.format("Lower bound: %1.2f%n", lower);
        System.out.format("Upper bound: %1.2f%n", higher);
        System.out.format("Increment: %1.2f%n", inc);

        for(double inp : inputs) {
            System.out.format("Input: %1.2f\tOutput: %d%n",
                    inp, rf.getRange(inp));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example:

```
Lower bound: 2.30
Upper bound: 3.90
Increment: 0.10
Input: 0.50 Output: 0
Input: 2.25 Output: 0
Input: 2.35 Output: 1
Input: 2.40 Output: 1
Input: 3.00 Output: 7
Input: 3.80 Output: 15
Input: 3.85 Output: 16
Input: 3.90 Output: 16
Input: 4.00 Output: 16
```

Comment: And the question is...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Performance

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The question seems to be - is there a faster way of doing division than with "/".

Comment: @DavidWallace It's possible the answer is "no, precalculation will not help you"

Comment: Well, why don't you try writing it using pre-calculation, and then do some comparisons?

Comment: Incidentally, you don't want `Math.round` on the last line, because it may round either up or down.

Comment: I seem to be missing something here. What "*to determine what range a given input double?*" actually means?

Comment: @PM77-1 Added an example for you

Comment: @DavidWallace Actually you need `Math.round()` because of double rounding errors. One reason not to use double division

Comment: Your code has several compile errors, the output is not a range, and the output is the same (1) for 2.25 and 2.34, is that correct?

Comment: @aditsu I just threw together a quick example. I've since cleaned it up and run it.

Comment: Ok, now it compiles, but the output is still not a range, and the result is still the same (but 0 this time instead of 1) for both 2.25 and 2.34. Note: 2.34 not 2.35.

Comment: @aditsu, this is part of the problem, because if you do `(int)` instead of `Math.round()` then you get the wrong answer in other situations.

Comment: If (higherBound - lowerBound)/increment is small, then it will be faster to do pre-calculation.  If it's large enough, then it will be faster not to, because you'll still have to do O(log n) comparisons; and for large enough n, this will be slower than division.  And please, get rid of the `Math.round` - it's just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line:

```
return (int) Math.round((number - lowerBound) / increment);
```

with this:

```
return (int) ((number - lowerBound + 1e-7) / increment);
```

It gives more sensible results, and runs about 30 times faster in my ad-hoc benchmark (because it doesn't call round anymore).
It's a good idea to declare the 1e-7 "epsilon" as a constant, and perhaps adjust its value to the error margin you require. Search for floating point rounding error (or something similar) to find out more about the subject, for example [this article](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/).

Comment: FYI I'm accepting this answer more for your help with these nasty imprecision errors than the performance stuff. That article is just awesome!

Comment: I think that the 'improved' replacement code that adds a magic 1e-7 number is a terrible idea. The whole point of floating-point numbers is that they support a wide range and a magic 1e-7 constant will only work (if at all) in a very narrow range.

If upperBound, lowerBound, and increment are all smaller than 1e-7 (say, 1e-60) then nonsense answers will be returned. If upperBound, lowerBound, and increment are all huge (say, 1e60) then adding 1e-7 will have no effect.

Comment: @BruceDawson that's why I talked about adjusting the error margin and linked that article for more information. 1e-7 will definitely work and is the easiest solution for the kind of numbers listed in the question.

Comment: @durron597 Ignore the last comment -- it got submitted accidentally.

I'm confused about why you are adding a constant. It will push numbers over the edge -- presumably to control 'undesirable' rounding at the edges, but it will also push numbers over the edge that should not be. A number that is 1e-8 below the boundary will be pushed over the boundary by adding 1e-7, and the wrong answer will be produced. I see no justification for adding 1e-7. Can you supply one?

BTW, I'm the author of the article that aditsu referenced.

Comment: @BruceDawson I guess you were talking to me. Btw you can delete your incomplete comment. Oh you're the author of that article? Then please refer to the "Epsilon comparison" section of your article :) Yes, the purpose of the constant is to push numbers like 3.9d (represented as 3.899999999...) over the actual 3.9 edge.

Comment: @BruceDawson If a number is 1e-8 below the boundary, then I'm assuming that is due to rounding errors, and pushing it over the boundary is correct. The OP is using only 1 or 2 digits after the decimal point, so that should be ok. If that assumption is wrong, then another epsilon or another technique from your article needs to be used. Relative epsilon would probably be safer.

Comment: @aditsu The trouble with adding an epsilon is that it doesn't *remove* the edge/cusp, it just moves it. If you are entering numbers like 3.9 that fall right along the edge then adding epsilon might improve the results, but in the more generic case where the numbers could be anything it is clearly incorrect. The epsilon makes the results less accurate.

The most that an epsilon can do is tell you that your input number is indistinguishable from one of the boundaries, and therefore the bucket number is indeterminate. That is, an epsilon should only be used if you want to give a fuzzy result.

Comment: @aditsu BTW, the use of an epsilon in a bucketing algorithm often indicates that you are doing something wrong at a higher level. If code keeps doing a round-to-nearest-integer on numbers like 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, etc. then that suggests an algorithmic problem. Maybe truncation would be better than round-to-nearest, or maybe the numbers need to be offset by 0.5.

Arguably that is just like adding a (very big) epsilon, but it should done more thoughtfully based on the meaning of the inputs. Pixel centers in graphics are a classic example of this.